# Explanation for the given function required

Tags: python, function

I am not able to understand the meaning of **'.'** in the function.

```
def getTrialCelli(grid):
  for i in range(grid_size):
    if grid[i] == '.':
      print 'trial cell', i
      return i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'.'` is the dot character. The one you put at the end of a sentence. Like->.

```
 if grid[i] == '.'
```

tests whether the `grid` list (probably a list) contains a dot at position `i`.

Answer (score 0):

This function checks if there is a character dot `.` in whatever `grid` is, a sentence or list. and prints out the position of it. (The index to wherever `.` was found)